# Why wrapper classes in Java are final?

Tags: java

Just simply as it sounds. I need to extend their functionality and I cannot. Why are they defined as final?

Example:

```
class MyInteger extends Integer
{

}
```

Comment: How do you want to extend their functionality?

Comment: Java has primitives, but they are not objects, or do you mean the `Integer`, `Long` etc types?

Comment: I want to add other functions to the type like maths functions with itself. Simply extend from Integer for example.

Comment: "I need to extend their functionality" There are other ways. What do you want to do exactly? Put ideal code in question, even if it wont compile.

Comment: I've put in the title objects. Types like int, long, etc are not objects Mark.

Comment: Just write methods that take those objects as parameters.

Comment: Right, what I mean is show the functions you want to add!

Comment: This is a workaround, I mean the design reason, why they are defined as final.

Comment: So you don't mess up their functionality.

Comment: You can still extend `java.lang.Number` and  provide your own subclass that expect instances of subclasses of Number.

Answer (score 21):

There are good reasons to makes the primitive wrappers final.

First, note that these classes get *special treatment* in the language itself - unlike any normal classes, these are recognized by the compiler to implement auto(un)boxing. Simply allowing subclasses would already create pitfalls (unwrapping a subclass, performing arithmetic and wrapping back would change the type).

Also, wrapper types *can* have shared instances (e.g. look at Integer.valueOf(int)) requiring that an instance of a wrapper is strictly immutable. Allowing subclasses would open up a can of worms where immutability can no longer be assured, forcing robust code to be written as if the wrappers were mutable, leading to defensive copies, wasting memory and CPU time and also creating issues with their usefulness in multi-threaded scenarios.

Essence: wrapper types need to be immutable to ensure uniform capabilities across all instances; immutablility being an important part of their known properties. And to guarantee immutability, the types *need* to be final.

If you need added functionality, implement it as utility class like you would do for primitives (see java.lang.Math for example).

---

Edit: To address the case made for "the classes needn't" be necessary final to ensure immutability. Strictly speaking this is true, the wrappers *could* be designed as non-final classes, only making *all* of the methods final. That would alleviate most of the pitfalls, but it leads to another issue: compatibility with new java versions. Imagine you decided to create your own subtype MyInteger sporting a new method, e.g. "Integer decrement()". Everything works fine, until... in Java 20 the language designers decide to add a decrement() method to the API (which would be *final* as discussed above). Bam, your class no longer loads, since it attempts to overwrite a final method.

Answer (score 5):

This is a security feature that lets libraries use strings and wrappers for primitives in collections or otherwise without making "defensive copies".

If users were allowed to derive their own values, say, from `Integer`, they could make a mutable version of it. Then they could pass instances of this `Integer` to a library that expects a collection of `Integer`s, like this:

```
class ApiClass {
    private final List<Integer> intList;
    ApiClass (List<Integer> ints) {
        // Make a defensive copy
        intList = new ArrayList<Integer>(ints);
        // Go through the list, and check the values
        ...
    }
}
```

Currently the constructor should make a defensive copy of the collection, but a shallow copy is sufficient, because `Integer`s inside cannot change. If Java did not insist on `Integer` being `final`, however, there would be no such guarantee, so the code would have to make a deep copy. Otherwise the caller could construct `ApiClass` by passing valid `Integer`s in a list, and then go through that list of `MyInteger`s, and change their values to what the constructor would consider invalid. This would break assumptions of other methods inside `ApiClass`, potentially causing crashes or exposing information that the "plain" `Integer` would not leak.

Comment: This is not correct.  The safety need explained in this answer could be satisfied by making the `int value` field final (actually, it already is) and also making the `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods final.  Thus, any subclasses of `Integer` would still be unable to modify the value, and would behave consistently as keys in a map.  So, I *suspect* that the correct answer to this question is: ...because there is this false notion shared by many people, that in order for a class to be immutable, it also has to be final.

Comment: @MikeNakis That wouldn't be sufficient - you would also need to make final `byteValue`, `doubleValue`, `longValue`, and so on down the list. Then you would have to make final the `compareTo` method, otherwise there could be "cheating" when using `Integer`s as keys in tree maps. At that point all of the methods would become final.

Comment: I agree that `compareTo()` would need to be added to the list, but I am not sure that there is a mechanism at play which requires more and more (and eventually all) methods to also be made final.  In any case, even if all methods needed to be final, that's still not the same as making the entire class final and thus preventing extension.

Comment: @MikeNakis A class can only be immutable (and trusted to be immutable) if there is no possible subclass that was designed to be mutable. If there is such class, then every method/class, that accepts the immutable type cannot be sure, that he won't get the mutable one (or he checks that explicitly). *Edit* See westons answer.

Comment: @Tom what you are describing is an issue that consumers (methods that accept the immutable type as parameter) of the immutable class need to worry about, not a problem of the immutable class itself.  You may make your immutable class also final in order to not have to worry about it in various places that you use it, but that's a convenience issue, not a logical issue.

Comment: [Example](http://ideone.com/JJqQiB) for that behavior. @MikeNakis Well, what is the point in having an immutable class if you can't trust it? (or trust the reference you're receiving)

Comment: If you *need* to trust the class, then you can assert that the object is of the specific class that you know you can trust.  But usually you do not even need to trust the class, because you are invoking specific methods which are final and therefore you already know you can trust.

Comment: @MikeNakis It would make perfect sense to assume that everything must be trusted for something as basic as `Integer`.

Answer (score 3):

They need to be immutable. And a key feature of correctly implemented immutability is it can't be extended. If you could extend you could do this:

```
class MyInteger extends Integer
{
    private int myOverrideValue;

    @Override
    public int intValue() {
      return myOverrideValue;
    }

    public void setIntValue(int value) {
      myOverrideValue = value;
    }
}
```

Now I can pass around objects of the mutable type `MyInteger` to classes and code that expects `intValue` to not change.

Answer (score 2):

**It can change the Behaviour of the methods in the Wrapper class.**

Let's say you have an `Employee` class that has a method `greet`. When the `greet` method is called it simply prints `Hello everyone!`. So that is the ***expected behavior*** of `greet` method

```
public class Employee {

    void greet() {
        System.out.println("Hello everyone!");
    }
}
```

Now, let `GrumpyEmployee` subclass `Employee` and override `greet` method as shown below.

```
public class GrumpyEmployee extends Employee {

    @Override
    void greet() {
        System.out.println("Get lost!");
    }
}
```

Now in the below code have a look at the `sayHello` method. It takes `Employee` instance as a parameter and calls the greet method hoping that it would say *`Hello everyone!`* But what we get is *`Get lost!`*. This change in behavior is because of `Employee grumpyEmployee = new GrumpyEmployee();`

```
public class TestFinal {
    static Employee grumpyEmployee = new GrumpyEmployee();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestFinal testFinal = new TestFinal();
        testFinal.sayHello(grumpyEmployee);
    }

    private void sayHello(Employee employee) {
        employee.greet(); //Here you would expect a warm greeting, but what you get is "Get lost!"
    }
}
```

This situation can be ***avoided*** if the `Employee` class was made `final`. Now it's up to your imagination the amount of chaos a cheeky programmer could cause if `Wrapper` Classes were not declared as `final`.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for this, activating this thread 5 years after, but i can't see any constructive suggestion for a solution - why don't you simply encapsulate it?

```java
public MyInteger {

  private Integer value;

  public MyInteger(Integer value) {
       this.value = value;
  }

//... Add your custom math methods here

}
```

Leaving this here if someone stumbles on this with similar questions :)